# Display current user's name in einstein analytics dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I am new to Einstein analytics.
I want to show the current User's name on the Einstein analytics dashboard. Can anyone please help me to do it.I have a text widget and I have added welcome note. 
But I need to add the current user's name. 
Thank you. 
Regards,
Sujendran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually not quite that hard.

Create a new query (pick any dataset) with the following SAQL

```
q = load \"MyDataset\";

q = group q by all;

q = foreach q generate \"!{User.Name}\" as UserName;
```

The important part is the !{User.Name}. This obviously gives you the Name of the current logged in User. For other options besides Name, refer to [Salesforce help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_dashboard_initial_filters_user_tokens.htm&type=0)

Then all that is left is binding this in your Text widget, like

```
"text": "Hello {{cell(lens_1.result, 0, \"UserName\").asString()}}",
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can do this with the binding and soql step

first :--
"UserData": {
    "groups": [],
    "numbers": [],
    "query": "SELECT Username, Country, FirstName, LastLoginDate 
              FROM User WHERE Name = '!{user.name}'",
    "selectMode": "single",
    "strings": [
        "Username",
        "Country",
        "FirstName",
        "LastLoginDate"
    ],
    "type": "soql"
}

you have to create a SOQL query like this and then

Second:---
"Billing_Country_2": {
    "groups": [],
    "isFacet": true,
    "label": "Billing Country",
    "numbers": [],
    "query": "q = load \"Opp_Icons\";\n
              q = group q by 'Billing_Country';\n
              q = foreach q generate 'Billing_Country' as 'Billing_Country', sum('Amount') as 'sum_Amount';\n
              q = order q by 'sum_Amount' desc;",
    "selectMode": "multi",
    "start": "{{cell(UserData.result, 0, \"Country\").asObject() }}",
    "strings": [],
    "type": "saql",
    "useGlobal": true
}

Do binding like this :--
you can also refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_bindings.meta/bi_dev_guide_bindings/bi_dashboard_bindings_wave_designer_initial_selections.htm
for more help